# Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on in my business class

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method in another dll that gets a lot of data (lopping 22k rows), and I need to create a progress bar for the user.

If I do not call this method asynchronously it hangs the application. But when I call it asynchronously I get the error `progressBar1` Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = tbPath.Text;

    ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);

    Task.Run(() => etlBusiness.LoadData(progressBar1));

}
```

In that case, `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync` is not asynchronous, it is stopping my application in looping

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = tbPath.Text;

    ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);

    Func<ProgressBar,int> func = etlBusiness.LoadData;

    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(func(progressBar1));

}
```

how fixed it?

Comment: "In that case, backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync is not asynchronous" Yes, yes it is.  You're just performing all of your work synchronously before you even call it, and passing the results of your expensive and time consuming operation as the parameter to the *start* of `RunWorkerAsync`, instead of having the worker actually do any expensive work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your control exists on thread A but you are trying to access it via thread B.  This is a 'no-no'.  Try the following code

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => LoadData(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current, progressBar1));
}

private void LoadData (System.Threading.SynchronizationContext synchContext, ProgressBar1ObjectType progressBar)
{
    string filePath = tbPath.Text;
    ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);

    synchContext.Post(state => etlBusiness.LoadData(progressBar), null);
}
```

Where 'ProgressBar1ObjectType' is the Type of progressBar1

Here is another option that may work better:

```
Thread _myThread = null;
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SynchronizationContext synchContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    _myThread = new Thread(() => LoadData(synchContext, progressBar1));

    myThread.Start();

}

private void LoadData (System.Threading.SynchronizationContext synchContext, ProgressBar1ObjectType progressBar)
{
    string filePath = tbPath.Text;
    ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);

    synchContext.Post(state => etlBusiness.LoadData(progressBar), null);
    _myThread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: i get null reference exception object reference not set to an instance of an object in synchContext.Post(state => etlBusiness.LoadData(progressBar1),null);

Comment: Sorry, edited with a possible fix.  If it happens again, check to see if 'progressBar' or 'etlBusiness' are null, if one of them are, then the problem is elsewhere.  If synchContext is null, let me know

Comment: I added this
public Home ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            synchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;

I did not receive a null reference exception, but the application is still locked

Comment: I added an alternate solution that may work better

Comment: the code works, but the application keeps waiting for the looping inside the etlBusiness.LoadData, I can not even close the program, I'm forced to wait for the looping to run out

Comment: I think you solved my problem in passing the context, and now I have another problem, the threed freezes the application, maybe I should open a new question and post the complete code

Comment: I think I see what the problem is, my bad, should have caught it sooner.  You need to move the logic of ETLBusiness.LoadData() inside the method that the new thread is calling, and the synchContext.Post should update the progressBar specfiacally.  You could also move the thread logic into ETLBusiness.LoadData().  Basically we (I, my bad) created a thread, and then passed operations back to the main/UI thread with the new one basically doing nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've helped me a lot.